# Linking an amount from a text input to a payment button field later on in process

Tags: php, html

I have an input on my websites processing page for amount:

```html
<input type="text" name="youhave" class="form-control" value="1" id="youhave" value="1"
```

then later on i have some payment buttons:

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://perfectmoney.is/api/step1.asp" 
method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYEE_ACCOUNT" value="U3492039">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYEE_NAME" value="Cryptonage">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_ID" value="Cryptonage">
<input type="text"   name="PAYMENT_AMOUNT" value="">               
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_UNITS" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="STATUS_URL" 
value="http://127.0.0.1/cryptonage.net">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL" 
value="http://127.0.0.1/cryptonage.net">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL_METHOD" value="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="NOPAYMENT_URL" 
value="http://127.0.0.1/cryptonage.net">
<input type="hidden" name="NOPAYMENT_URL_METHOD" value="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="SUGGESTED_MEMO" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BAGGAGE_FIELDS" value="">
<input type="submit" name="PAYMENT_METHOD" value="Pay with PerfectMoney">
</form>
```

how can i change it so that the amount given in the first part of processing is processed as "PAYMENT_AMOUNT" later on when you click the payment button in the second part without having to type the amount again in the text field next to the button. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In previous page create a form and in action of that form pass the link of this page that you have mentioned above

---

```
Example(previous page where amount is entered):
<form target="_blank" action="https://perfectmoney.is/api/step1.asp" 
method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" value="1" id="amount" value="1">

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

---

```
Example(current page where amount is to be shown):
<form target="_blank" action="https://perfectmoney.is/api/step1.asp" 
method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYEE_ACCOUNT" value="U3492039">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYEE_NAME" value="Cryptonage">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_ID" value="Cryptonage">
<input type="text"   name="PAYMENT_AMOUNT" 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$amt =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['amount']);
echo 'value="'.$amt.'" disabled>'
}else{
echo 'value="0" disabled>'
}         
?>      
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_UNITS" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="STATUS_URL" 
value="http://127.0.0.1/cryptonage.net">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL" 
value="http://127.0.0.1/cryptonage.net">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL_METHOD" value="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="NOPAYMENT_URL" 
value="http://127.0.0.1/cryptonage.net">
<input type="hidden" name="NOPAYMENT_URL_METHOD" value="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="SUGGESTED_MEMO" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BAGGAGE_FIELDS" value="">
<input type="submit" name="PAYMENT_METHOD" value="Pay with PerfectMoney">
</form>
```

---

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but i can't get it to work. i have made the question less broad added all code and simplified my question. Thanks :)

Comment: updated the answer you can check it now....hope it works